# Regex to match a url/link with line breaks

Tags: python, regex, url

I want match url from references.But some url has line brakes in it.

Example text = Yale Project on Climate Change Communication. New Haven, CT: xxx University and George
Mason University; 2015. p. 1–62. Available from: https://example.xxx.edu/wp-content/
uploads/2015/04/Global-Warming-CCAM-March-2015.pdf.

want to match: https://example.xxx.edu/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Global-Warming-CCAM-March-2015.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ([Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/c82HZb/2))

```py
txt = """\
Yale Project on Climate Change Communication. New Haven, CT: xxx University and George
Mason University; 2015. p. 1–62. Available from: https://example.xxx.edu/wp-content/
uploads/2015/04/Global-Warming-CCAM-March-2015.pdf. This is another text just for example"""


import re

pat = re.compile(r"https?://[\S\n]+")

for url in pat.findall(txt):
    print(url.replace("\n", "").strip("."))
```

Prints:

```
https://example.xxx.edu/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Global-Warming-CCAM-March-2015.pdf
```